# How do I configure OpenCart for prices that already include tax?

Tags: ecommerce, opencart

I've set up OpenCart 2 on my server. The products I sell have 21% "BTW" (VAT). When I add a product with a price, OpenCart assumes the price is without taxes, but the prices I type in are already including the taxes.

How can I let OpenCart assume the prices I type in include the taxes? Or if that isn't possible by default, how would I change OpenCart's source code for that? I don't want to use an extension…

Comment: Calculating the before tax price as you enter the price is not possible?

Comment: @w3dk: That isn't possible in this case…

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can disable the taxes and enter the prices including tax.

Go to Admin Dasboard > Settings > Edit Store >

[image: Settings - Options]

In Option tab select Display prices with out taxes

[image: Display prices with tax]

Comment: Please provide the main points of the linked article in your answer. Link-only answers are generally not received very well on this site (as they can become stale).

Comment: @w3dk Thanks for editing the answer i might unknowingly violated rules